# wheezy not accepting commands

Tags: debian, apt

I have debian Wheezy on an independent Dell amd64 how do I get to accept commands to install a virtual box?  here's what I put in terminal (also tried in root terminal):

```
$ vi /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list
```

it accepted this, but, then, I put in:

```
$ deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian wheezy contrib
```

and I got: E35 No previous regular expression
any help would be grateful.

Comment: What **exactly** did you put in that file? Is that `$` sign in here? It shouldn't be.

Comment: As Gilles stated, I think that `$ deb http://...` line should not have the `$ ` at the beginning of it. It should just be: `deb http://...`.

Comment: @Gilles, @slm: perhaps I misunderstood the OP, but I believe the `$`s just demonstrate that it was a command run at a shell.

Comment: @HalosGhost I meant the `$` sign on the second line. I haven't checked whether it would cause this error.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert but this should work:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Copy and paste the following line into the nano window:

```
deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian wheezy contrib
```

Then:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-4.3
```

Here is the [official](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads) webpage.